# Apps Script to search for names and file paths in folders by name

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-apps-script

I'm making [apps script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10BNjBYrv1vzZ-eL7EzXVFd1RUfSxLwWWvTPNW1EWztg/edit#gid=0) to find files that don't contain the names "Done" and "InProgress".
[image]
The script that I have created is like this:

```
function testSearch(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1gr0RIGIt0AEzEqIxJigGxYlxQGy8yLqp')
  var allFile = parentFolder.getFiles()

  var filter = parentFolder.searchFiles('fullText not contains "Done"' && 'fullText not contains "InProgress"');

  var cnt = 0;

  while (allFile.hasNext()) {
    var filter = allFile.next();
    cnt++;
      var data = [
        filter.getName(),
        filter.getUrl(),
      ];
        sheet.appendRow(data);
   }
}
```

After I run the script, the results do not match.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve files in the specific folder.
- You want to retrieve all files with the filenames which don't include `Done` and `InProgress`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modifiaction?

#### Modification point:

- You can directly retrieve files with the filename using the search query of `not title contains 'Done' and not title contains 'InProgress'`.

#### Modified script:

```
function testSearch(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1gr0RIGIt0AEzEqIxJigGxYlxQGy8yLqp')

  var files = parentFolder.searchFiles("not title contains 'Done' and not title contains 'InProgress'"); // Modified

  var cnt = 0;
  while (files.hasNext()) { // Modified
    var file = files.next();
    cnt++;
    var data = [
      file.getName(),
      file.getUrl(),
    ];
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about `cnt` in your script.

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

  - This is for Drive API v3. When you use Class DriveApp, please use the parameter for Drive API v2.
  - In your case, the filename is `title`.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

When you want to retrieve files in the subfolders, please use the following script.

#### Sample script:

```
function testSearch(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1gr0RIGIt0AEzEqIxJigGxYlxQGy8yLqp')
  function getFiles(folder){
    var files = folder.searchFiles("not title contains 'Done' and not title contains 'InProgress'");
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var data = [
        file.getName(),
        file.getUrl(),
      ];
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    var folders = folder.getFolders();
    while (folders.hasNext()) getFiles(folders.next());
  }
  getFiles(parentFolder);
}
```

Comment: The script is running, but the file in the sub folder does not appear.

Comment: In the parent folder there are sub folder, named test1 and test2.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ev3g.png

Comment: @Lutfi Creativesys Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that you wanted to retrieve files in the subfolders. I apologize for this. I added a sample script. Could you please confirm it? I apologize the script is largely changed from your original one.

Comment: Solved. Thanks you so much @Tanaike